# How can I change the default image shape in PyTorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I've noticed that PyTorch uses images with shape (channels, width, height). How can I change it to (width, height, channels)?

I am looking for a switch kind of think which switches between the two modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `torch.permute`:

```
tt = torch.tensor([[[0, 0], [1,1]], [[0,1], [1,0]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]])
# > tensor([[[0, 0], [1, 1]],
#           [[0, 1], [1, 0]],
#           [[2, 2], [2, 2]]])
print(tt.shape)
# > torch.Size([3, 2, 2])

tt2 = tt.permute(1, 2, 0)
# > tensor([[[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2]],
#           [[1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2]]])
print(tt2.shape)
# > torch.Size([2, 2, 3])
```

Comment: That works too but I was looking for a "switch" kind of thing which switches between the 2 modes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any possibility to change Torch's default `CHW` mode to `HWC`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for inplace operation, you can use `torch.view`

```
t = torch.rand((3, 224, 224)) # [C, W, H]
t.shape
# torch.Size([3, 224, 224])

t.view(224, 224, 3).shape # [W, H, C]
# torch.Size([224, 224, 3])
```

[From pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html)

> View tensor shares the same underlying data with its base tensor. Supporting View avoids explicit data copy, thus allows us to do fast and memory efficient reshaping, slicing and element-wise operations.

Comment: `torch.view` is not suitable for a CHW->HWC conversion. It's **similar** to a `reshape`, not to a **permutation-type** operation that is needed.